# Unable to bind to a view with compose containerless code

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

This is *kind of* related to my recent question about multiple views within one page.  I started with the Durandal sample knockout shell and attempted to extract the navigation menu on the left into its own "navList.html/navList.js" view/viewmodel.

I created navList.html and navlist.js:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li class="nav-header">Basic Examples</li>

    <!--ko foreach: introSamples-->
    <li data-bind="css: { active: isActive }">
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, text: title"></a>
    </li>
    <!--/ko-->

    <li class="nav-header">Detailed Examples</li>


    <!--ko foreach: detailedSamples-->
    <li data-bind="css: { active: isActive }">
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, text: title"></a>
    </li>
    <!--/ko-->
</ul>

define(['plugins/router', 'knockout'], function (router, ko) {
var childRouter = router.createChildRouter()
    .makeRelative({
        moduleId: 'ko',
        fromParent: true
    }).map([
        { route: '', moduleId: 'helloWorld/index', title: 'Hello World', type: 'intro' },
        { route: 'helloWorld', moduleId: 'helloWorld/index', title: 'Hello World', type: 'intro', nav: true },
        { route: 'clickCounter', moduleId: 'clickCounter/index', title: 'Click Counter', type: 'intro', nav: true },
        { route: 'simpleList', moduleId: 'simpleList/index', title: 'Simple List', type: 'intro', nav: true },
        { route: 'betterList', moduleId: 'betterList/index', title: 'Better List', type: 'intro', nav: true },
        { route: 'controlTypes', moduleId: 'controlTypes/index', title: 'Control Types', type: 'intro', nav: true },
        { route: 'collections', moduleId: 'collections/index', title: 'Collection', type: 'intro', nav: true },
        { route: 'pagedGrid', moduleId: 'pagedGrid/index', title: 'Paged Grid', type: 'intro', nav: true },
        { route: 'animatedTrans', moduleId: 'animatedTrans/index', title: 'Animated Transition', type: 'intro', nav: true },
        { route: 'contactsEditor', moduleId: 'contactsEditor/index', title: 'Contacts Editor', type: 'detailed', nav: true },
        { route: 'gridEditor', moduleId: 'gridEditor/index', title: 'Grid Editor', type: 'detailed', nav: true },
        { route: 'shoppingCart', moduleId: 'shoppingCart/index', title: 'Shopping Cart', type: 'detailed', nav: true },
        { route: 'twitterClient', moduleId: 'twitterClient/index', title: 'Twitter Client', type: 'detailed', nav: true }
    ]).buildNavigationModel();

return {
    router: childRouter,
    introSamples: ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(childRouter.navigationModel(), function (route) {
            return route.type == 'intro';
        });
    }),
        detailedSamples: ko.computed(function () {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(childRouter.navigationModel(), function (route) {
                return route.type == 'detailed';
            });
        })
    };
});
```

...which are pretty much identical copies of the original index.html and index.js files.

I then turned index.js into this:

```
define(['ko/navList'], function(nav) {

    return {
        router: nav.router
    };
});
```

and index.html into this:

```
<div class="container-fluid knockout-samples">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2 well">
        <!--ko compose: {view: navList, 
            transition: 'entrance'} -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </div>
      <div class="span10">
          <!--ko router: { transition:'entrance', cacheViews:true }--><!--/ko-->
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

...which is not a major change.  All I'm trying to achieve at this point is education via tinkering. I figured that if I could deconstruct/reconstruct a working example I'd be a step further along my line of understanding of how to structure my app.

Of course, where this goes wrong is on the binding to navList.  It appears that despite being told to go and look for navList as a view, it's treating it as part of the index.js model as far as I can tell so I get this in the console window:

```
Binding ko/index 
Object {router: Object, __moduleId__: "ko/index"}
 system.js:75
Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: compose: {view: navList, 
            transition: 'entrance'} 
Message: navList is not defined;
View: ko/index;
ModuleId: ko/index
```

Could some kind soul please explain the fundamental understanding issue I have here please?

Solution:
As pw kad suggested, using the container "data-bind" syntax in index.html instead of containerless as I was trying to do has fixed the problem.  The code is now:

```
<div class="container-fluid knockout-samples">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2 well" data-bind="compose: 'ko/navList'"></div>
      <div class="span10">
          <!--ko router: { transition:'entrance', cacheViews:true }--><!--/ko-->
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use compose: "viewmodels/navList" where navList.js is in app/viewmodels/ folder

Comment: For amoment there I thought that was going to be another of your "I can't believe it was so damn easy" answers but I still get the same error in chrome console about being unable to parse bindings. Although this time it refers to "compose: {viewmodels: navList" in the relevant place.

Comment: Are you using compose: '' or compose: {}?  Refer to the docs, you should be using compose: '' http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition/

Comment: I was using it exactly as shown above: "<!--ko compose: {..." as I was trying to use containerless binding but I've now got it changed to the data-bind: syntax as: <div class="span2 well" data-bind="compose: 'ko/navList'"></div> (as navList.html and .js live in the ko subfolder, not the viewmodel subfolder).  This works (yahoo!) but I'm intrigued why I couldn't use containerless binding?  Have edited original question for clarity of code.

Comment: You can you just have to look at what durandal is expecting to be passed in.

Comment: I would gladly look what durandal is expecting, but there's nothing about containerless binding on that page you linked to above so I'm not sure what to use for the containerless syntax!  Is it the "view:" bit that I'm getting wrong?

Comment: Remember that the container less bindings are available from knockout, and the compose is just a custom binding that Durandal makes available.  Check the binding in Durandal to see what it expects, since this is an open source project you can just look at the code instead of solely relying on the docs

Comment: That assumes I have the javascript nous to work it out and I'm not at that level yet. I tried using the chrome debugger to step through but I'm way out of my depth there so I haven't got a clue what that code is trying to do.  I'm happy that it works with the data-bind syntax. I may trip over the containerless syntax somewhere and then I may be able to reverse-engineer it from that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want to put your second comment in the section above (about reading the docs) in as the answer I'll get it accepted as that's what enabled me to work out what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ko compose: 'viewmodels/navList' to instantiate the view model and view from your parent view.  This allows Durandal to map using the default viewLocator in your app/viewmodels/ folder.

check the docs for more info

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition/